# Union not giving desired results while and operator does?

Tags: sql, union

why in this query AND operator is giving the result but Union seems not to be working ?

First:

```
select distinct(city) 
from station  
where city not like ('A%') 
  and city not like ('E%')  
  and city not like ('o%')  
  and city not like ('i%')  
  and city not like ('u%')
```

Second:

```
select distinct(city) 
from station  
where city not like ('A%') 
union 
select distinct(city) 
from station  
where city not like ('E%')
```

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a` and `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` and `distinct a,b`

Comment: `UNION` behaves like an `OR`

Answer (score 2):

These queries will give you 2 different output:
First one will select all cities with *not* **A E o i u** as first letter

The second query will give you results:

1st result set: all cities except A%

2nd result set: all cities except E%

after union : all cities including A% and E%

Comment: Actually, the result you get **after union will also include E%** since UNION will distinctly merge the resultset from 1st query(everything except A%) and 2nd query(everything except E%). So this answer is inaccurate.

Comment: Yes, you re right. My mistake. "The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use UNION ALL". Answer fixed

Answer (score 0):

- First query gives you a single resultset, where City does not start
  with AEoiu.
- Second query separately gets two result sets, where City
  does not start with A & city does not start with E and then UNIONs
  them. So, you will have cities in the first result set starting with
  Eoiu & cities in second result set starting with Aoiu. So, UNION of
  them gives you a result set distinct cities of resultset 1 & 2(cities starting with AEiou). This will not match with first result set, where cities does not start with AEiou.

Hence, First and second resultset gives completely different result set.